# Give another account the same access as s3 bucket owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've written an app (in lambda) that accesses S3 in a corporate environment - basically lots of different people *write* to the s3 bucket, from loads of different accounts, which ends up with a whole collection of permissions in each.    One thing everyone does is include the owner-full-control.

On the read side - the app goes through various CI stages - unfortunately each one is on a different S3 account, each one needs read access to the bucket - and none of them are the owner of the s3 bucket.  While I have shown we can go to s3 and individually add read privileges for a different account to a single object

- there's a few accounts, they could change, and I dont necessarily know them all
- it is really expensive timewise to do, as you sort of have to recopy each of the s3 files over itself
- I have no control over people who add *new* stuff to the bucket, so no way of ensuring that they add these new permissions going forwards into the future

So what I want to do is configure it so that either:

- my app can read *anything* in the s3 bucket, regardless of the object permissions
- my app can act go into the bucket with the same permissions as the s3 owner (even though it's actually a different account)

now - I don't agree with the account structure or the fact that everything seems to live in a different account, but this is a corporate thing I have no power over.   I do sort of own the s3 bucket so can get permissions/policies put on that.

Comment: "read anything in the s3 bucket, regardless of the object permissions" - sorry, but this does not make sense to me. If it was possible, what would be the point of permissions in the first place?

Comment: Sadly, your question is not clear. What is your current bucket policy? How does your lambda access buckets in other accounts? Though assuming cross-account roles? What are the permissions on the role? What is lambda execution role?  How exactly do you "add read privileges for a different account to a single object"? Bucket policy should give you access to everything. If you are not the owner of the objects, you can only delete the objects. Its the same as with permissions. There is no point in ownership, if you could mimic the ownership of objects.

Comment: Can't you just add a Bucket Policy to the bucket that grants access permission to the other AWS Accounts? That way, you won't need to change the permissions on the actual objects.

Comment: Marcin - what I want in the perfect world is to NOT have object permissions.  I want to be able to give permissions at the bucket level. If you can read the bucket, you can read everything IN the bucket - simple as that.  There is no value to me/ it's causing problems to have permissions more granular than at the bucket level.

Comment: john - that's EXACTLY what my question is asking about, but I can't figure out how - at the bucket level other account X has been given permissions - so I can read or write using account X to that bucket.  I just can't read anything written by account Y.